# Limit entries and truncate new entries

Tags: mysql, truncate

I was wondering if there was a simple solution in MySQL to truncate MySQL entries.

For example:

I want only a maximum of 100 entries in one table. If a new entry is submitted, (101st entry) then it would delete - lets say - the last entry (ordered by a time stamp) and insert the new one (still only having 100 entries).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at mysql triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the problem using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html).

A trigger is a routine that is called when elements are inserted, deleted, or updated. So you could define a trigger that is run when a new element is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

i do not think that is possible in mysql
(http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,42315,175712#msg-175712).

create view on your table with limit 100 and order by date.
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html)